# eclipse to use g++-4.exe not g++.exe

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, g++, cygwin

I use `eclipse` to write `c++` programs. I have both `g++ 3.4` and `g++ 4.x` in `/cygwin/bin` directory, and I want `eclipse` to use `g++-4.exe` not the other one (named `g++.exe`). How can I say to it to use `g++-4.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Preferences menu, then search for Compiler. And should you have any problem with the setup, follow this article about Eclipse CDT installation:
[Eclipse CDT](http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/cdt.jsp%20Eclipse%20CDT)